# how to find minimum values across different dates in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe 
data

```
Date          Marks
21-01-2019     18
22-01-2019     12
23-01-2019     14 
24-01-2019     20
25-01-2019     16
19-02-2019     12
20-02-2019     11
21-02-2019     18
22-02-2019     15 
23-02-2019     20
24-02-2019     14
```

I wanted to group the data by month and that particular year to get the minimum marks. My output looks as shown below:

```
Date          Marks
22-01-2019     12
20-02-2019     11
```

Comment: In case your `Date` column is a literal string (since it is not in R's default `Date` format), I suggest that you actually make it a `Date` object with `as.Date(df$Date, format="%d-%m-%Y")`. While it might be easy to keep it as a string, your question suggests that the ordinal nature of dates is important to your handling of the data, so it should be stored as such.

Comment: (In case you do change to a `Date` object from your posted example, realize that Chris's answer's use of `substring` will need to be adjusted, since R's default format is year-first.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the minimum per months and years, you can do (it involves `dplyr`):

```
df %>%
 group_by(Date = format(as.Date(Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y"), "%m-%Y")) %>%
 summarise_all(min)

  Date    Marks
  <chr>   <int>
1 01-2019    12
2 02-2019    11
```

And the same with `base R`:

```
aggregate(Marks ~ cbind(Date = format(as.Date(Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y"), "%m-%Y")), 
          FUN = min, 
          data = df)
```

If you want to return also the corresponding date:

```
df %>%
 group_by(month_year = format(as.Date(Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y"), "%m-%Y")) %>%
 slice(which.min(Marks)) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-month_year)

  Date       Marks
  <chr>      <int>
1 22-01-2019    12
2 20-02-2019    11
```

And the same with `base R`:

```
df[df$Marks == with(df, ave(Marks, format(as.Date(Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y"), "%m-%Y"), 
                            FUN = function(x) x[which.min(x)])), ]
```

Comment: This isn't the expected output. I think you need to (a) convert to `Date`, and (b) group on a new column, so that `min(Date)` works as expected. If the OP needs it to remain in the non-`Date` format post-summary, then you can always `format` again.

Comment: @r2evans I see, I had the impression that the OP wants just the minimum per individual months and years :)

Comment: Yes, and the nitnoid detail is that the `Date` column should retain its current formatting. It's just a detail, good fix.

Answer (score 3):

Since you know the fixed date format, you can just cut off the day part and group by that. You can group_by in order to add the minimum marks for every row, grouping by the year/month, and then filter out all rows which were not equal to the minimum.

```
table %>%
  mutate(ym = substring(Date, 4)) %>%
  group_by(ym) %>%
  mutate(min_marks = min(Marks)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(Marks == min_marks) %>%
  select(-ym, -min_marks)
```

Edited to account for finding the day(s) with the minimum marks. Note that this may produce multiple rows if there are multiple dates with the same minimum marks.

Comment: @r2evans Sorry, that was a phone autocorrect - I've fixed it.

Comment: I'm not brave enough to post answers (with code blocks) from my phone ... :-)

Comment: Date          Marks
22-01-2019     12
20-02-2019     11

Comment: @Prad Sorry, I missed the complete intent of your original post - I've edited my answer to account for returning the dates.

Answer (score 0):

data.table + lubridate example:

**Data**

```
dt = data.table(
  Date = seq(as.Date('2001-01-27'), as.Date('2001-02-03'), 1),
  Marks = rnorm(8)
)

> dt
         Date       Marks
1: 2001-01-27 -1.43603728
2: 2001-01-28 -1.02685408
3: 2001-01-29  0.37307426
4: 2001-01-30 -0.79033901
5: 2001-01-31  0.05463855
6: 2001-02-01  1.62495320
7: 2001-02-02 -0.44335638
8: 2001-02-03 -0.66227100
```

**Code**

```
dtsum = dt[, .(Date = Date[which.min(Marks)], MinMark = min(Marks)), .(Month = month(Date))][, 2:3]

> dtsum
         Date   MinMark
1: 2001-01-27 -1.436037
2: 2001-02-03 -0.662271
```

Comment: Close, but missing year: *"group the data by month **and that particular year**"*.

Comment: Right you are! Read the question too hastily. Hang on.